# Button onclick, adding function to trigger is not working

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am rather begginer in terms of riot.js and i have a problem. I am using riot.js start-kit [Riot Webkit on GitHub](https://github.com/wbkd/riotjs-startkit) .

I am trying to invoke function by clicking on a button. I craetet list.tag and assigned setAlert there, and in the script part i created setAlert(e) and here's the problem, because it throws me and error :

```
client:47 ./src/components/itemlist.tag
Module build failed: Error: SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (13:11)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\Marco\Documents\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\riotjs-loader\index.js:37:11)
 @ ./src/pages/home.tag 5:0-37
```

If i delete this setAlert(e) everything is fine.
Please help me. Here's my code :

```
<list>
    <button onclick={setAlert}>Alert!</button>

    setAlert(e) {
        alert('Button clicked')
        }
</list>
```

Comment: I managed to get this working here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bDUNSsPhl4ZdOtFiN6Rz?p=preview

Are you sure that you have included the riot library with the compiler?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my compiler or babel maybe ? Everything else is working untill i try to declare function.

Comment: hmm, can you make a plunkr or a jsfiddle with your code on it?

Comment: Take a look at error log :

Comment: Babel doesnt understand riot's short function syntax. `this.setAlert = function() {}` or es6 version`this.setAlert = () => {}` should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, with this.setAlert it  all worked ! I figured it out on my own, but thank you for the answere !